# Not constructive flag on comments declined

Tags: discussion, flagging

Why were those 2 not constructive flags declined?

[First flag](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/99906/can-ram-retain-data-after-removal/99924#comment172358_99924)

> Interesting link, thanks

[Second flag](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/101504/laptop-anti-theft-measures/101509#comment175926_101509)

> +1 on FDE as practical advice

Perhaps the second has some small value, though to me it still feels like a redundant comment. But I truly don't understand how the first comment could be useful in any way; it's noise that should be removed.

<sub>Note: I don't know which exactly where the comments declined since the decline-link points to the post instead of the declined comment, but I am assuming i flagged the ones i linked above.</sub>

Comment: for the record, I agree those should be removed. Perhaps because they are more of "too chatty" worthy than "not constructive" (which sounds more negative, rather than just extraneous)?

Comment: also, I've removed the comments in the meantime, cuz why not.

Comment: @AviD I flagged them as "not constructive" since they don't contribute to the discussion (as in, provide any useful related information). They are "too chatty" as well but.. are "too chatty" handled in the same way as "not constructive"? I had the impression that "too chatty" aren't immediately deleted. I tend to flag such comments on SO always as "not constructive" for that reason.

Comment: For the second one, if the answer simply said "use FDE" then just upvoting the answer provides as much info as the comment and the comment should be deleted. But if the answer said "use FDE and foo", then I think the comment adds some value beyond upvoting of the comment author feels strongly about FDE but not about foo.